# Lost Xbox 360 data

Tags: xbox-360

I have had my 360 for a couple years now and just recently upgraded to an xbox live account. I created a brand new one using a gamertag that xbox live choose for me. After doing that, however, I found that any of the offline saved data from previous games was erased (NBA 2k14 and NCAA10). I have signed in to all the gamertags on my account and can't find it anywhere. Is there a way to recover this? Or am I just out of luck?

Comment: Was the data definitely there before you made a live account?

Comment: Yes, I use the same xbox for all my games. Just added a new account for xbox live

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the achievements and save data in your other profiles can't be transferred to your new Live account.  Like you, I found that out the hard way.

Comment: This seems to be mostly correct, although it doesn't explain why the other accounts on the console would show the data.

Comment: So do I lose them all together? I created a new account and even my older accounts don't show any history.

Comment: The older accounts not showing data is another issue altogether.   In regards to achievements and game saves transferring from one Live account to another, you're screwed.  The other thread that was posted that this may be a duplicate of may have some answers.